# Replace 8 spaces tabs with 4 spaces tabs

Tags: vim, vimrc

I added `set tabstop=4` `set softtabstop=4` `set shiftwidth=4` to my .vimrc file.

But tabs in my existing files are still taking 8 spaces. How can I update them?

Comment: Did you `source ~/.vimrc` yet?

Answer (score 2):

Because you mentioned updating 8 space tabs in existing files...
Run substitute on those existing files individually `:%s/        /    /g`

Your method for .vimrc defined tabstop changes tabs in my documents. Possibly you have document specific session files or vim settings in the file.
 See this post for a possible cause and solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313463/storing-vim-settings-with-a-document

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify your files so that a hard tab is replaced by the appropriate number of spaces, then you can filter them through `pr`.

Load the file in `vim`, make sure you're at the first line (`1G`), then filter the entire file: `!Gpr -e4 -t`<kbd>enter</kbd>

`pr -e4` means to *e*xpand hard tabs to spaces using tabstops 4 apart; the `-t` tells `pr` not to paginate the file (it's usually used to format a file for printing, hence its name).

You can also do the reverse with `-i` (for *i*mplode).

For reference, see [POSIX pr](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/pr.html).

Comment: Or just use "`:retab`" in Vim.